# Vue axios post request blocked by CORS policy

Tags: vue.js, cors, axios

Vue axios post request

```
axios.post(`${this.host}:${this.port}/apiv2/login`, {
        body: {
          userName: this.user,
          password: this.pwd
        }
      });
```

resulted in ERROR:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9047/apiv2/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

python requests, postman or simple curl does the job without errors

```
curl 'http://localhost:9047/apiv2/login' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"userName":"user","password":"pass"}'
```

**UPDATE:**
Here my solution:

I added NodeJS server (localhost:8081). Now Vue (localhost:8080) is accessing NodeJS and NodeJS is quering Dremio API (localhost:9047).

The idea of having just static Vue app didn't work.

Comment: Which technology are you using for your Backend?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn’t Postman get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when my JavaScript code does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-doesn-t-postman-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on)

Comment: I query from vue (localhost:8080) a Dremio server api (localhost:9047)

Answer (score -1):

1st: Try add `{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}` inside  and then try again.
If not work, then go to your "Localhost:8080" and set Access Control Origin to * then try first step again

Comment: In production, this would make the server vulnerable to XSS. Not recommended.

Comment: Yes, I mean if this step works, then continue to setup cors.